# Make html footer occupy the rest of the body

Tags: html, css, height, footer

So I am trying to code the footer of my web app of it occupies the rest of the body's height.

Picture: http://img1.uploadscreenshot.com/images/orig/3/8906151296-orig.png

Notice the light area beneath the dark area, the dark area should occupy all of it.

Some of my html code:

```
<body>
....
<footer>
    <hr>
    <ul id="footerContainer">
        <li class="right">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="" class="family-filter">Filtro Fami....</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</footer>
<script>...</script>
</body></html>
```

CSS:

```
....
#footerContainer {width: 90%; min-width: 525px; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;}
....

footer hr{ border: 0; height: 30px; background: url('../imgs/footer-top.png') repeat-x scroll; }
footer {
  background: url('../imgs/footer-bg.png') repeat scroll bottom;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto; 
}
#footerContainer {margin: 0 auto; position: relative;}
#footerContainer li { display: inline;}
#footerContainer li .right {float: right;}
#footerContainer li a {}
```

Any suggestions?

Update1:

This is what happens: http://img1.uploadscreenshot.com/images/orig/3/8906391235-orig.png when I set

```
html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Update2:

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0382hf1ff

Zoom out and in at this page: line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/blog-design-coded/demo/… and check the footer area, that's how I need it work on my layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mikey/RxMnU/4/)

Giving an element `height: 100%` means that it occupies 100% of the closest parent that has 
height defined. In this case you don't know the footers height, because the height of the content is variable.

I don't know the rest of your html structure, but you could give the `body` a white background-color and the content div dark grey.

Comment: Do you mean you want this?
http://jsfiddle.net/Mikey/RxMnU/3/

Or have the footer background texture repeated? -> set that texture as `background: url(...)` in the `body`.

Comment: you don't get it... the background is only for footer and has to repeat its self and there must not be an fixed height, but an automatic one.

Comment: Zoom out and in at this page: line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/blog-design-coded/demo/… and check the footer area, that's how I need it work on my layout.

Comment: And what if the content height + footer height is less than the window height? In my JsFiddle I gave the footer a height because I don't have your footer background image and the footer is empty.

Comment: This is the best I could make of it. If it's still not what you want, I do not really understand what you want, then I give up :).
http://jsfiddle.net/Mikey/RxMnU/4/

Or try the sticky footer: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 2):

There is a very useful demo of 100% height here:

[100% Height Demo](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html)

This could be tweaked to fit your requirements.

Comment: thanks for the info, I already knew about this one. The problem is that I do not want to alter my current html code

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is set the background-color of the `html` and `body` elements to be that of your footer. Then set the background-color of your content area to the lighter gray color.

```
html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}
#content {
    background-color: silver;
}
```

Comment: So you don't want those fixed buttons on either side to go below the top of the footer? Please be more descriptive about what you want.

Comment: Zoom out and in at this page: http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/blog-design-coded/demo/index.html and check the footer area, that's how I need it work on my layout. Ignore the side buttons, they go down or up as you scroll. On normal zoom with `html, body{height: 100%}` and same height on footer, the footer extends like in the photo

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you want. Your screenshot appears to look exactly like the example site you posted. If you still have the height: 100%; set on your footer, you might try removing that. Maybe that is your problem. The styles I posted in my answer should give you exactly what you want.

Comment: in the screenshot of my site, there was no zoom out... that's how it apears on normal scale

Comment: The footer will collapse as the page content above it takes more space. Add more content to your footer and the page body and it should work just fine. You also may have a height set somewhere that's causing the footer to extend down too far.